# Create VM on New Azure Portal from Captured sysprep Image Or Allocate Reserved IP on Old

Tags: azure

I have an image captured from a VM of a 2012 Server that has had Sysprep executed.

Using the old Azure portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com) I've been able to create new VM - all my tests confirmed the Sysprep & Capture have worked.

The Old portal (UI) doesn't allow you to create & assign a new reserved IP when creating the VM.

Whereas, the new portal (https://portal.azure.com ) allows you to create & assign the reserved IP at the point the new virtual machine is being created.  I'd prefer to use the new portal & select the image I've created.

Is there a way to select the image via the new Azure Portal when creating a new VM?

If not, am I correct in believing that you can't reserve & allocate via the old portal?

Failing that I'll revert to using a powershell script to provision new vms from the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and Yes. At this moment you can't deploy a VM using a captured image but you can create a new VM with reserved IP whereas the oposite is true to the old portal. If you need help with powershell scripts you can follow this guide i've written this week regarding redeployment of existing vms with reserved ip.

http://www.azurekb.com.br/reserve-ip-address-to-an-existing-virtual-machine/

Comment: Many thanks Bruno, I thought as much.  As you say, powershell is still the way to go.

Comment: Who's the f***** project manager on this?  How can you design a new product with new features without covering the features on the old design.  I'm constantly jumping from the classic to the new portal and back again.